# How do I select a collection using a string name

Tags: scripting

How do I select a single collection using a string and making it the active selection? Any ideas please.

I'm aware of selecting objects in collections, looking for how to pick a specific collection by string.

(python)
I know it's to do with this:

bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate(deselect_all=True)

--

How do I get it to be like this? (**Mock Up**)

bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate("MyCollection")

*EDIT -
You can delete this question as I found an alternative way in doing what I needed to do.*

Comment: Appears that you can't :S https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.outliner.html?highlight=outliner#module-bpy.ops.outliner

Comment: Since people have made an effort to answer this question, rather than deleting it I would ask you to write up your alternative for people who have the same problem in the future, please.

Comment: I never explained I wanted to select a collections so when it's active I can press f2 to rename it. Instead of looking for it in the hierarchy and renaming it there. I use pie menus to run small code snipets: bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection(collection_index=0, is_new=True) worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

You need to access from the context master collection.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

def recurLayerCollection(layerColl, collName):
    found = None
    if (layerColl.name == collName):
        return layerColl
    for layer in layerColl.children:
        found = recurLayerCollection(layer, collName)
        if found:
            return found

master_coll = context.view_layer.layer_collection
current_coll = recurLayerCollection(master_coll, bpy.context.collection.name)
target_coll_name = "Lights"
target_coll = recurLayerCollection(master_coll, target_coll_name)

if target_coll:
    context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = target_coll
else:
#    create a new collection in the master scene collection
    target_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(target_coll_name)
    context.scene.collection.children.link(target_coll)
    target_coll = recurLayerCollection(master_coll, target_coll_name)
    context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = target_coll
```

Comment: How about `target_coll = bpy.data.collections.get(target_coll_name)` instead of using the `recurLayerCollection`?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady causes an error when trying to set as active collection. TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: ViewLayer.active_layer_collection expected a LayerCollection type, not Collection

Comment: Aah, I see, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady If you happen to know or find a better way to set the active collection in the view_layer please let us all know since this is a bit much.